# trying to use an MVVM to add an object to a list

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

okay, I'm trying to apply the MVVM pattern to my c# project, and I'm facing this error.

in mainView.xml.cs i created an mainviewmodel

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

to connect the view with the view model.

in the mainviewmodel.cs I implement a save method to save vehicle

```
    private void SaveVehicle()
    {
        bool success = false;
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle()
        {
            VehicleId = _vechicleId,
            Longitude = _longitude,
            Latitude = _latitude,
        };

        success = _context.AddVehicle(vehicle);
        

        if (success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sucsess adding a vechicle");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Call 911");
```

I got an error that says _context is null and I don't know why this is happening.

my add method:

```
    internal bool AddVehicles(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        vehicles.Add(vehicle);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is `_context` and where do you set it? What is `vehicles`?

Comment: Please read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what type is vehicles?

Comment: private BusinessContext _context; and BusinessContext has a list of vehicle witch im trying to add the vehicle in it

Comment: "_context is null" - where do you set `_context`?

Comment: I set it in the mainviewmodel parameters. mainviewmodel(Businesscontext context){
_context = context;}

Comment: can you post the entirety of your mainviewmodel class

Answer (score 0):

in your comments you mention that you are doing

```
mainviewmodel(Businesscontext context){ _context = context;}
```

but in the code you are showing you are only doing

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

so this is not what's happening

you need to do

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(Businesscontext);
```

or

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(){
    Context = Businesscontext
}
```

this is assuming you have a

```
public Businesscontext Context { get=> _context; set=>_context = value;}
```

however once you have the _context set you will still not see any update on your collection
because your databinding wont't updating because it doesn't know the model has changed

Binding on collections defaults to using the CollectionChanged event of INotifyCollectionChanged List does not implement this this interface and so doesn't tell the binding to update

instead you could use an [Observable Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0)

Comment: im not trying to update i just want my vehicle to be added in the list, should i use Observable Collection for it

Comment: when you create the list its empty, you then add something to it, that's an update